How many Lunar Module Ascent Engines survive?
There are 2 of these on display at the Niagara Aerospace Museum in Niagara Falls NY. I wonder how many others still exist?

Looks like you asked this question 4 years ago: How many Lunar Module Ascent Engines were produced? How many still exist?. If the answer given there satisfies you, please mark it as accepted.
